# How to make Ember.js load RESTAdapter data before showing view?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I have a app with RestAdapter that takes proper data from server:

```
App.AFile= DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr( 'string' ),
...

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({url: "myapi"})
});
```

And a map like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('allfiles', { path: '/allfiles' });
  this.resource('onefile', {path: '/onefile/:onefile_id' });
```

And routes defined like this:

```
App.allfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
      return App.AFile.find();
  }
});

App.onefileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params)
  {
      return App.AFile.find(params.onefile_id);
  }
});
```

And those templates:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="allfiles">
 {{#each controller}}
    {{#linkTo onefile this}}open{{/linkTo}}
 {{/each}}
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="onefile">
   {{name}}
 </script>
```

It works like this: user opens app and it displays allfiles template with a link called open. The link opens a template called onefile and passes the onefile_id to it.

When i open app and click open it works and displays proper name of one file. URL is set to #/onefile/1 where 1 is the onefile_id. So it works fine.

But when i refresh page (#/onefile/1) than name is not displayed anymore.

I've checked what is going on and in onefileRoute model function before i return the id and it occurs that App.AFile has null values for all fields defined. And after app loads those values are filled properly in the App.AFile object but are not displayed on the view.

So it looks like RestAdapter gets data after view display.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.onefileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(params)
  {
      var m = App.AFile.find(params.onefile_id);
      // at this point m might not be resolved, so name could be empty
      return m;
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition){
      // at this point it should be resolved, what happens here?
      console.log(model.get('name'));
  }
});
```

My guess would be your endpoint is returning the wrong information for a model by id.

Comment: In aftermodel model.get('name') still returns null

Comment: In Chrome, if you watch the network tab are you seeing the call and response?